# localhost developed site is slow

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have problem with my localhost website(s). The situation is very strange, it started happening days ago. The developed site(s) are using cache and normally they are rendered for 0.3 seconds, but now if I open one page of one of my websites it takes around 6-10 seconds to be rendered. I have tried also with page, where there is only 1 mysql query, so that page also needs 6-10 seconds to be loaded.

But the strange thing is that page is loaded so slow only the first time, if I continue clicking on links of that website, they load normal. Than if I do some other stuff (f.e. coding in notepad++ for 1 minute) and than open again any page, it takes again 6-10 seconds to load.

Somehow apache/php/mysql is sleeping in that time in that I do not browse, but I don't know why. As I mentioned, that happens couple a days ago ...

I have made also a test with website, where there is only plain html files - there I don't have that problem.

I appreciate your help !

Comment: What OS are you using? Has the OS had any updates around the same time?

Comment: I am using Windows. Unfortunately i don't remember the exact date, when that started happening so I check if it is from any update :(

Comment: This could be caused by numerous things. Try the simple things first. Disable the cache, clear out the cache and restart cache, shutdown apache/php/mysql and restart, shut down web server and computer and restart. You might also want to clear out the web browser cache.

Comment: Have you looked in the Browser debug, network panel for any outside requests.  One time I had a google font that was trashing my performance on localhost.  I forget why now, but it was un-reachable and was pausing loading the page tell it timed out... etc. It was very irritating to figure out.  I would also suggest doing some basic bench marking to see where all the time is being spent.

Comment: @jeff: what do u mean by disable the cache? The browser cache or to disable the cache service for the website. Now i saw that even phpmyadmin takes also time to be loaded for the first time.

Comment: @VinceCarter the web server cache.

Comment: @jeff i am not sure how to clear out the server cache. The other things i have done, but nothing happend

Comment: if that can help to find out the problem. When i call some scripts from the command line, it is the same. The first call takes more time than usual